# Receiving Japanese keyboard input from a custom view

Tags: android, unicode, localization

I'm currently working on a kind of Japanese grammar quiz program in which you see a sentence in japanese with one or more blanks and type in the answer using the japanese IME.

For example, a question would show up like this:
彼は勉強＿＿＿＿スポーツ＿よくできる。

and you'd fill in the blanks like this:
彼は勉強もちろんスポーツもよくできる。

Because I want to animate text on the screen in special ways, I have forgone using a simple edittext.  Each blank/underlined character in the question has its own separate image view, and the input cursor is moved to whichever is clicked. When one of the imageviews is pressed it should bring up the Japanese romaji keyboard WITH predictive text so that users can input Kanji when necessary.

How can I make it so that when an imageview is clicked it makes the Japanese Romaji keyboard pop up with predictive text on?  How do I capture the user's key presses (on either a hard or soft keyboard). Also, what if the user doesn't have the japanese romaji keyboard installed?  (It's absolutely necessary)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really force the user to use a particular keyboard. You can open the soft keyboard, if it happens to be set to, say, Greek, that's what the user will see. If they don't have or don't select a Japanese IME, they won't be able to use your app, so just tell them so :)

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I was afraid of.  If they happen to have the japanese IME how do I make that show up as the default input method?  When they click on the imageview I want the Japanese keyboard to pop up with predictive text turned on, because they will need to input kanji.  When I force the keyboard open in my app, I can only switch to the default english keyboard or the number keyboard.  The Japanese IME option is greyed out.

Comment: You can't force it, you can only open the currently selected keyboard. On Andorid 2.x, you need to long press on text field to switch, on HC and ICS, the switch is in the action/status bar. Since you have a custom view, maybe there is something you need to implement you are missing. Try it out with a TextView first, then compare with your custom view.